# pgfplots enlarge y limits doesn't seem to do the trick

Tags: pgfplots, scaling

I'm a bit confused about how `enlarge y limits` should work.

I'm trying to give myself a bit of room above and below the graph.  This is a generic example, but I'm trying to embed it in a macro eventually, so I can't use `ymax` and `ymin` explicitly, because I don't know in advance what will be plotted.

Currently, the resulting plot is way too close to the y limits to look good (in my opinion).

I created this [mwe]https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=zzvrzs.

But it doesn't seem to actually expand the y limits (I see no difference with and without the `enlarge y limits` command).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
     enlarge y limits=true,
     restrict x to domain=0:10, xmax=10, xmin=-1,
     x=1cm,
     y=1cm,
     axis x line = middle,
     axis y line = middle,
     axis line style = thick,
     major tick style=black,
     minor tick num=1,
     >=stealth,
     xticklabels=,
     yticklabels=,
     ]
        \addplot[thick,domain=0:10,color=blue] {-3*2.71828^(-x/2)+1}; 
        \node[fill=blue,circle,scale=0.2,color=blue] at (0,-2) {$ $};
        \node[color=blue, anchor=east] at (axis cs:0,2) {$b$};
        \node[below left] at (axis cs:0,0) {$0$};
        \node[below] at (axis cs:9.8,-0.1) {$t$};
        \node[left] at (axis cs:-0.1,3.8) {$label$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph showing not enough y space]

Comment: Have you tried using a number instead of `true`? E.g. `enlarge y limits = 0.15`

Comment: yes, but that also didnt work.  I also tried the {abs=1} option which also didn't work for me.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `x = 1cm` and `y = 1cm`? Does that change anything?

Comment: It changes the output, but it isn't clearly adding space on top and bottom.  It just stretches things out vertically, but doesn't add space outside of the y limits.